# Which integers can be expressed as a sum of three cubes in infinitely many ways?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

For fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ consider integer solutions to
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=n \qquad (1) $$

If $n$ is a cube or twice a cube, identities exist.

Elkies suggests no other polynomial identities are known.

> For which $n$ (1) has infinitely many integer solutions?

**Added**

> Is there $n$, not a cube or twice a cube, which allows infinitely
>   many solutions?

Added 2019-09-23:

The number of solutions can be unbounded.

For integers $n_0,A,B$ set $z=Ax+By$ and consider
$x^3+y^3+(Ax+By)^3=n_0$. This is elliptic curve
and it may have infinitely many **rational** points
coming from the group law. Take $k$ rational points
$(X_i/Z_i,Y_i/Z_i)$. Set $Z=\rm{lcm}\{Z_i\}$.

Then $n_0 Z^3$ has the $k$ integer solutions $(Z X_i/Z_i,Z Y_i/Z_i)$.

Comment: Let $n = 1, 2$ and we have solutions for $x, y, z$ with a value $t \in \mathbb{N}$ however not *all* $x, y, z$ are positive, though I think this may serve as a little bit of help: $$\begin{align} 1 &=  (9t^3 + 1)^3 + (9t^4)^3 + (-9t^4 - 3t)^3 \\ 2 &= (6t^3 + 1)^3 + (-6t^3 - 1)^3 + (-6t^2)^3 \end{align}$$ or for *big* solutions for $n = 1$: $$1 =  (1 - 9t^3 + 648t^6 + 3888t^9)^3 + (-135t^4 + 3888t^{10})^3 + (3t - 81t^4 - 1296t^7 - 3888t^{10})^3$$

Comment: The expression for n = 2 should read: $(6t^3 + 1)^3 + (- 6t^3 + 1)^3 + (- 6t^2)^3 = 2$ That is, the 2nd sign in the 2nd pair of parentheses should be + rather than -.

Comment: @joro: Using [Huisman's results](https://arxiv.org/src/1604.07746v1/anc/sumofthreecubes_20160426.txt), one finds that $$x^3+y^3+z^3 = 972$$ already has $96$ solutions in the "small" finite range that he searched. Similarly for other $n$. It is tempting to speculate that, if the range were infinite, then it and others in fact have infinitely many solutions like $n=1$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII What if in general the solutions are exponentially growing?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Sums of three cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes) contains some results on this and also quite long list of references.

Comment: I already upvoted this, so I can't get it from 41 to the ideal number 42 of upvotes for this question.  Hopefully, someone else will come along eventually to do the right thing.

Answer (score 35):

For $n\equiv \pm 4\pmod{9}$ there is no solution to $(1)$. Otherwise, for $n\ge 1$, it is conjectured that there are always solutions, even infinitely many.
There are no analytic results, but heuristics suggest that
given $n$, not $0$ or $\pm 4\pmod{9}$, solutions should occur infinitely often,
asymptotically $c\log(N)$ solutions in $|x|,|y|,|z|<N$, see papers of Conn and
Vaserstein.

The topic has been discussed quite frequently, see also
[sum of three cubes and parametric solutions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126186/sum-of-three-cubes-and-parametric-solutions/126713#126713), [Are nontrivial integer solutions known for $x^3+y^3+z^3=3$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58188/are-nontrivial-integer-solutions-known-for-x3y3z3-3), [Efficient computation of integer representation as a sum of three squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104322/efficient-computation-of-integer-representation-as-sum-of-three-squares), etc.
For a collection on polynomial parametric solutions, see https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/010.

See also the Euler-Binet solutions to $x^3+y^3=z^3+w^3$,
$$
x = 1 − (p − 3q)(p^2 + 3q^2),
$$
$$
y = −1 + (p + 3q)(p^2 + 3q^2),
$$
$$
z = (p + 3q) − (p^2 + 3q^2)^2,
$$
$$
w = −(p − 3q) + (p^2 + 3q^2)^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you. So unless n is a cube or twice a cube no infinite solutions are known?

Answer (score 27):

As stated by Dietrich Burde, it is known that there is no solution for $n\equiv \pm 4 \pmod{9}$, and conjectured that there are infinitely many solutions otherwise.

A cryptic aspect is that it is not even known that there exists one solution for all $n \not\equiv \pm 4 \pmod{9}$.
Today the smallest number for which the problem is open is $n=114$.

Here is a (non-exhaustive) history of the latest solutions found for $n \le 100$ (see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1997-66-218/S0025-5718-97-00830-2/S0025-5718-97-00830-2.pdf) and [there](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2007-76-259/S0025-5718-07-01947-3/S0025-5718-07-01947-3.pdf)):

(1960s)

- $87 = 4271^3 – 4126^3 – 1972^3$
- $96 = 13139^3 -15250^3 + 10853^3$
- $91 = 83538^3 – 67134^3 – 65453^3$
- $80 = 103532^3 -112969^3 + 69241^3$

(1990s)

- $39 = 134476^3 - 159380^3 + 117367^3$
- $75 = 435203083^3 – 435203231^3 + 4381159^3$
- $84 = 41639611^3 – 41531726^3 – 8241191^3$

(2000s)

- $30 = 2220422932^3 – 2218888517^3 – 283059965^3$
- $52 = 23961292454^3 - 61922712865^3 + 60702901317^3$
- $74 = 66229832190556^3 − 284650292555885^3 + 283450105697727^3$

(2019)

- $33 = 8866128975287528^3 - 8778405442862239^3 -2736111468807040^3$
- $42 = 80435758145817515^3 - 80538738812075974^3 +  12602123297335631^3$
- $3 = 569936821221962380720^3 - 569936821113563493509^3 - 472715493453327032^3$
- $906 = 72054089679353378^3 -74924259395610397^3 + 35961979615356503^3$
- $165 = 383344975542639445^3 -385495523231271884^3 + 98422560467622814^3$

*Remark*: for $n \le 1000$, the problem is still open only for $114$, $390$, $579$, $627$, $633$, $732$, $921$, and $975$ (see [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-266/S0025-5718-08-02168-6/S0025-5718-08-02168-6.pdf) and [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07746v1.pdf), and also [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40993-019-0162-1)).

Numberphile's videos:

- [The Uncracked Problem with 33](https://youtu.be/wymmCdLdPvM?list=LLhntpxxSKIETTxsQMN8nywg)
- [42 is the new 33](https://youtu.be/ASoz_NuIvP0)
- [NEWS: The Mystery of 42 is Solved](https://youtu.be/zyG8Vlw5aAw)

Comment: The number 33 has now been expressed as a sum of 3 cubes. See https://pub.ist.ac.at/~tbrownin/.

Comment: $$33=(8866128975287528)^3+(-8778405442862239)^3+(-2736111468807040)^3$$ According to this address, the discoverer should be [Tim Browning](https://ist.ac.at/research/research-groups/browning-group/).

Comment: It was actually Andrew Booker in Bristol that found this solution!

Comment: The preprint of Andrew Booker: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maarb/papers/cubesv1.pdf

Comment: The links in this post are broken

Comment: The number 42 is now known to be a sum of three cubes: $(-80538738812075974)^3 + 80435758145817515^3 + 12602123297335631^3$.  I found this on Drew Sutherland's website.

Comment: @KConrad: Is it due to Drew Sutherland or Andrew Booker or someone else?
The question is motivated by the fact that Tim Brownin did the same website for $33$ but he was not the author of the computation.

Comment: Andrew Booker's website has the same status as Drew's right now.  I don't know which person (or rather which person's computer) it is due to, but will write to Drew and ask.

Comment: I guess $114$ is the new $42$.

Comment: I heard back from Drew. He and Booker worked together on this, and the change of their websites to show only the representation of 42 was inspired by how Browning made Booker's result for $33$ known.

Comment: There’s a video interview with Booker in which he talks about the 42 discovery, at https://youtu.be/zyG8Vlw5aAw

Comment: The same team has now found a new solution for three: $3 = 569936821221962380720^3 + (-569936821113563493509)^3 + (-472715493453327032)^3$

Answer (score 22):

https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/010 cites
the following polynomial identity $$(m^3-3^6n^9)^3+(-m^3+3^5mn^6+3^6n^9)^3+
(3^3m^2n^3+3^5mn^6)^3=m(3^2m^2n^2+3^4mn^5+3^6n^8)^3$$ valid for any $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Thanks. But the RHS varies as m,n vary so this doesn't represent fixed n?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This identity does not produce infinitely many integer solutions. It only proves Ryley's Theorem that "any non-zero rational number $m$ is the sum of three rational cubes in an infinite number of non-trivial ways.”