# Decidability of $x^3+y^3+z^3 = c$

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, decidability

I wondering if it is known whether the following problem is algorithmically decidable or undecidable by Turing machines: given an integer c, determine if there are integers $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^3+y^3+z^3=c$.  If the status is unknown, what are the conjectures or consensuses on the decidabiity of such small cubic equations?

Comment: Poonen's article "Undecidability in number theory" begins: "Does the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 29$ have a solution in integers? Yes: $(3, 1, 1)$, for instance. How about $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 30$? Again yes, although this
was not known until 1999: the smallest solution is $(−283059965, −2218888517, 2220422932)$. And how about $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 33$? This is an unsolved problem."

Comment: The latest relevant reference seems to be Elsenhans, A.-S. and Jahnel, J. "New sums of three cubes". *Math. Comp.* **78**, 1227 (2009).

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways . To my knowledge, it is expected that the only obstruction is the obvious 3-adic condition that $c \not\equiv 4,5 \bmod 9$, but a proof seems to be far away. If this expectation is true, then of course there is a pretty trivial Turing machine that will decide the question... Colliot-Thélène and Wittenberg [Groupe de Brauer et points entiers..., Amer. J. Math. 134 (2012), no. 5, 1303–1327] have shown that there is no Brauer-Manin obstruction for the other $c$.