# If $a^3+b^3+c^3=N$, then $x^3+y^3+z^3+t^3 = N$ in infinitely many ways?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, open-problems

It is well-known that,
$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = N\tag1$$
for $N=1,\,2$ is solvable in the integers in *infinitely* many ways . However, it is an open question ([but is conjectured](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways)) that if for general $N$ it has a solution, then it must have infinitely many. I'd like to propose a variant,

> **Conjecture:** If $a^3+b^3+c^3=N$, then $x^3+y^3+z^3+t^3 = N$ in infinitely many ways.

Part I: Use the identity,

$$x^3+y^3+z^3+t^3 = (a^3+b^3+c^3)\big(p^2+(a+b)cq^2\big)^3$$

where,

$$\begin{aligned}
t &= a p^2 - c^2 p q + b (a + b) c q^2 \\
x &= b p^2 + c^2 p q + a (a + b) c q^2\\ 
y &= c p^2 + (a^2 - b^2) p q\\ 
z &= -(a^2 - b^2) p q + (a + b) c^2 q^2\end{aligned}$$

Part II: Solve the *Pell equation*,

$$p^2+(a+b)cq^2 = 1\tag2$$

This is the tricky part since we require $(a+b)c<0$. Perusing through [S. Huisman $15254$ solutions](https://arxiv.org/src/1604.07746v1/anc/sumofthreecubes_20160426.txt), I find that ***all*** his solvable $N$ have solutions where both $a,b$ are negative, or $c$ is negative. Of course, $(2)$ can then be easily solved as a Pell equation.

> **Q:** If $(1)$ has a solution in positive integers, then how do we prove that implies a subsequent solution where one or two of the variables are negative?

**P.S.** The second solution may be *huge*,
$$4^3+ 4^3+ 7^3 =-17863863023^3+ 13242033973^3+ 15005424841^3 = 471$$
but it guarantees infinitely many solutions to $(2)$.