# Quadratic factors of $l_1(x,y)^3+l_2(x,y)^3+l_3(x,y)^3-n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Related to sum of three squares and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways).

Let $l_1,l_2,l_3 \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Assume that $n$ is not a cube and not twice cube.

Let $f=l_1(x,y)^3+l_2(x,y)^3+l_3(x,y)^3-n$.

Is it possible $f$ to factors as $f(x,y)=q(x,y)g(x,y)$
where $\deg q=2$ and $q=0$ is absolutely irreducible and
have infinitely many integral points, giving infinitely
many representations of $n$ as sum of three cubes?

For $n= -1$ this is possible:

$l_1=2*x - 1;l_2=-x + y;l_3=-2*x - y;q=x^2 + 9*x*y + 9*y^2 + 12*x - 6$

Possible approach is to equate coefficients symbolically.

Comment: Isn't $-1$ a cube ?

Comment: @HenriCohen Yes, it is cube. Just to show it is possible in general.